# C# Adding New Form to List error

Tags: c#, forms, list, addition

I am trying to create a new form, and then add it to a list, but I get the error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Here is my code:

---

```
List<Form> Forms;
```

---

```
public void addform()
{
   string name = "FormName";
   Form newform = new Form();
   newform.Name = name;
   newform.Text = newform.Name;
   newform.ShowDialog();
   Forms.Add(newform); //I get the error here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
List<Form> Forms;
```

simply creates a new reference, called Forms. Its value is null. No list has been created or assigned to the variable. If you try to call methods on this reference, it will fail.

If you instead write:

```
List<Form> Forms = new List<Form>();
```

you are creating a new empty List-of-Form-objects on the managed heap, and assigning the reference to the Forms variable. This is now a valid list, and can be added to without problem.

Comment: Sorry - I'm in a bit of a rush to finish my program, and I'm making loads of silly mistakes...

Answer (score 4):

You need to create instance of your list like this

```
List<Form> Forms=new List<Form>();
```

This should work